# React renders d3 charts outside the body

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs, ref

I'm trying to generate a test environment to work on D3 using `React`.

I'm using the following code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    d3.select(this._testChart)
        .data(this.state.data)
        .enter().append('div')
        .style('background-color','blue')
        .style('color', 'white')
        .style('width', d=>d*10 + 'px')
        .text(d=>d)
}

render(){
    return (<div className='TestChart' ref={(c) => this._testChart = c}>
        </div>)
}
```

I'm getting the `ref` for the `div`, and then in `componentDidMount()`. I'm appending the `div` which generates a basic bar chart. Now, when I run this code, I'm seeing the bar chart, but it's getting rendered outside the body of the HTML. I guess I'm not using `ref` correctly. How can I get the chart inside the body?

Answer (score 1):

Your d3 selector should find the element by class name, not the React ref.

```
componentDidMount(){
    d3.select(".TestChart" )
        .data(this.state.data)
        .enter().append('div')
        .style('background-color','blue')
        .style('color', 'white')
        .style('width', d=>d*10 + 'px')
        .text(d=>d)
}

render(){
    return (<div className='TestChart' 
        </div>)
}
```

Comment: How are you mounting your react component?

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); I mean I am attaching it to the 'root' div. It's interesting because a div with class name 'testChart' is getting created in the 'root' div, but the appended d3 div's are getting attached outside the body of the html